# Conditional composition in Hydra

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I'm new to Hydra, so sorry for the nooby question.
Update: Thanks, [Omry Yadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930838/omry-yadan) for pointing out an example would be helpful. Indeed while putting it together I realize that I was not providing enough information.
My question revolves around the use of Structured Config schemas.

I have the following minimal example for reproduction.
My folder structure is:

```
./my_app.py
./config/config.yaml
./config/strategy/Strategy1.yaml
./config/strategy/Strategy2.yaml
```

The individual files contain the following content:
`./my_app.py`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import MISSING, DictConfig, OmegaConf


@dataclass
class StrategyConfig:
    name: str = MISSING


@dataclass
class Strategy1Config(StrategyConfig):
    name: str = "strategy1"
    alpha: float = MISSING


@dataclass
class Strategy2Config(StrategyConfig):
    name: str = "strategy2"


@dataclass
class MyConfig:
    strategy: StrategyConfig = field(default_factory=StrategyConfig)


cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="base_config", node=MyConfig)
cs.store(group="strategy", name="base_strategy1", node=Strategy1Config)
cs.store(group="strategy", name="base_strategy2", node=Strategy2Config)


@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="config", config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: MyConfig) -> None:
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

`./config/config.yaml`:

```
defaults:
  - base_config
  - strategy: Strategy1
  - _self_
strategy:
  alpha: 0.1
```

`./config/strategy/Strategy1.yaml`:

```
defaults:
  - base_strategy1
name: strategy1
alpha: ???
```

`./config/strategy/Strategy2.yaml`:

```
defaults:
  - base_strategy2
name: strategy2
```

Running the default command `python my_app.py` or equivalently `python my_app.py strategy=Strategy1`:

```
strategy:
  name: strategy1
  alpha: 0.1
```

Running `python my_app.py strategy=Strategy2`, we get this error:

```
In 'config': ConfigKeyError raised while composing config:
Key 'alpha' not in 'Strategy2Config'
    full_key: strategy.alpha
    object_type=Strategy2Config
```

What I expect the outcome to be however is:

```
strategy:
  name: strategy2
```

i.e. I expect it to ignore the setting of alpha to 0.1 in `config.yaml`
Indeed, when commenting out those two lines in `config.yaml`, I get the expected output.
When removing the notion of schemas and "base_strategy", the above command outputs:

```
strategy:
  name: strategy2
  alpha: 0.1
```

Which I understand, but would like to avoid.

I expect I have an incomplete understanding of Structured Config Schemas in hydra.

Thanks for any pointers.

Mat

Comment: Please update your question to include a fully reproducible example. It will help answering your question without guessing what you have actually done.